# ReactJS URL to receive auth token from OAuth2

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0

I would like to know the best way I can create an URL in React to receive the Auth token in the query that would be called through a redirect URL from the OAuth2 Authorization server.

What I plan to do is to create a component with a route and that would be the URL I will set as the redirect URL. From there, I will use `useEffect` function to know that the URL has been called and send an API request to authenticate for the AccessToken.

But creating an empty component for this doesn't sound right to me and I want to know is there is a better way to do this.

The flow I am using is OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code with PKCE Flow

Answer (score 1):

It is usual to do these 3 things:

- Plug in the OIDC Client security library
- Set the redirect URI to the main URL of your app
- Handle login redirects as part of the main page load

It is a design pattern really and nothing to do with React. There are a couple of samples of mine that may help:

- [Initial Code Sample](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/25/basicspa-execution/)
- [React Code Sample](https://authguidance.com/2019/04/08/how-to-run-the-react-js-spa/)

Of course, you may be able to implement the same pattern in a more cutting edge React manner.